# File uploading can not work using Struts 2 and Uploadify

Tags: file-upload, struts2, struts, uploadify

**My JSP page like this:**

```
$(function() {  
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({  
        'height': 27,
        'width': 80,
        'buttonText':'浏览',
        'swf':'<%=basePath%>admin/tupian/js/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': '<%=basePath%>Imguploadoper.img',
        'auto' : false,
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.jpg'
        });
});
```

**Here is my java code:**

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
upload.setHeaderEncoding("UTF-8");
try {
    //this line returns null
    List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator itr = items.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        ......
    }
} catch (FileUploadException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

`upload.parseRequest(request)` returns `null`. I really don't know the reason.

Comment: Make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2422468/1065197

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake when uploading in Struts2. You shouldn't parse the request in the action. I believe that you've written the java code in the action. So, Struts2 handles multipart request via the [`MultipartRequestWrapper`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/multipart/MultiPartRequestWrapper.html), which is using the configuration constant

```
struts.multipart.parser=jakarta
```

that corresponds to the multipart request adapter [`JakartaMultiPartRequest`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/multipart/JakartaMultiPartRequest.html), used to *parse* the request and put files to the location defined by this constant [`struts.multipart.saveDir`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Handling+File+Uploads), if this constant isn't set then `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` used by default.

You can get [`MultipartRequestWrapper`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/multipart/MultiPartRequestWrapper.html) using `ServletActionContext`, see
[How do we upload files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/How+do+we+upload+files).

Then [`fileUpload` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload-interceptor.html), which is a part of the `defaultStack`, using the maltipart request get all accepted files, accepted file names and accepted content types and put them to the action context.

Then [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html), which is a part of the `defaultStack`, using that action context params, put them to the action properties.

When multipart request wrapped, which is done by the `Dispatcher`, and *parsed* when wrapper is instantiated, you can check files in the `saveDir`, if uploading finished without errors.

To perform file uploading make sure you submit the multipart request, i.e the form `enctype` attribute is `"multipart/form-data"` and interceptors are applied to the action explicitly referencing them or implicitly using `defaultStack` of interceptors. In the action create properties with getters/setters for file names, content types, and files. If your uploads are succeeded then check your files in the action properties.

To learn more you can exercise these examples:

- [Struts 2 file upload example](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/upload-file-with-struts-2)
- [Struts 2 upload multiple files example](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/upload-multiple-files-with-struts-2)